# error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arduino

Someone of you can help me with code issue? I got the generic compiling error:
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

with this part of code code:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) { 

   PotValue[i] = analogRead(PotPin[i]);   //This is the error line

   MappedPotValue[i]=(PotValue[i]+1)/103;

 //SomeCode Here
}
```

So. My target is to write in PotValue Array all the values of all Pots in Arduino Board

PotValue and MappedPotValue are int arrays of 2 lenght

And PotPin has been declared as:

```
#define PotPin {A0, A1} // These are two analog pins on arduino board
```

the for loop is inside a timer interrupt

thx for help

Comment: What argument does `analogRead` take?

Answer (score 2):

```
analogRead(PotPin[i]);
```

gets parsed as:

```
analogRead({A0, A1}[i]);
```

Which is a syntax error. There are no array literals in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the preprocessor. Use this instead of the `#define`:

```
static const int PotPin[] = {A0, A1};
```

(adapt the type `int` as needed).